# How to search for a StringBuffer object in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

Following is the code snippet I am working with.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
ArrayList<StringBuffer> al = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
while (N-- > 0) {
   str = new StringBuffer(sc.next());
   if (al.contains(str)) {
       System.out.println("Duplicate value " + str);
   } else {
       al.add(str);
   }    
}
```

If the input is:
4

abc

fgh

dfg

abc

It is showing blank output when the expected output is:

Duplicate value abc

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `StringBuffer` at all here? It'd be easier just to use `String`.

Comment: @AndyTurner  I was using StringBuffer because as a part of the actual bigger problem statement, I have to reverse the string, which only can be done with StringBuffer. Am I correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StringBuffer` doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`, so when you search if your `List` contains a certain `StringBuffer` instance, you are checking if the exact reference appears in the `List`.

You could use a `HashSet<String>` to avoid duplicates, since `String` overrides `equals`, and then (if you must) create a `List<StringBuffer>` from the elements of the `HashSet`.

BTW, `StringBuilder` is more efficient than `StringBuffer` (which should only be used if you plan to access it from multiple threads).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
ArrayList<StringBuffer> al = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<>();
while (N-- > 0) {
   uniques.add(sc.next());
}
for (String s : uniques)
    al.add (new StringBuffer(s));
```

If you have to report the duplicates, a small change will be required :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
ArrayList<StringBuffer> al = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<>();
while (N-- > 0) {
   String str = sc.next();
   if (!uniques.add(str))
       System.out.println("Duplicate value " + str);
}
for (String s : uniques)
    al.add (new StringBuffer(s));
```

Comment: HashSet is a good suggestion. But my problem statement says me to print a message when it encounters a duplicate value. In your solution, it just collects the unique values in an arraylist. Am I correct?

Comment: @SatyajitPatnaik That's easy enough to achieve. See edit

Comment: Oh yes, I could have done that before posting the comment. I ran that. But, I guess the add() method of HashSet object only takes String objects, but I need StringBuffers so that I could add them before reversing them. That is why I posted about StringBuffers in my query itself. Can we do anything about that?

Comment: @SatyajitPatnaik You can't use StringBuffers in HashSet, but my suggested solution only uses the Strings to eliminate duplicates. After that I create a List of unique StringBuffer instances. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Actually I want the arraylist of StringBuffers before hand, and not after finding the unique values. It is like, if a string is given, it should be able to be reversed (StringBuffer) and then added to an arraylist. Then for the next String given, it should check if it is present in the arraylist (if yes, it will be a pallindrome of an earlier string which was reversed and put into the arraylist). If yes, I should stop taking anymore input strings, and print the value which matched the condition. In my case, al.contains(strbuff) was not working.

Comment: @SatyajitPatnaik You can create a StringBuffer from the String, reverse it and check if the reversed String is in the HashSet. `if (!uniques.add(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code as below:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
ArrayList<StringBuffer> al = new ArrayList<>();
while (N-- > 0) {
    str = new StringBuffer(sc.next());
    //if (al.contains(str)) {
    if (al.stream().anyMatch(stringBuffer -> stringBuffer.toString().equals(str.toString()))) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate value " + str);
    } else {
        al.add(str);
    }

}
```

In code above

```
if (al.contains(str)) {
```

Changed to

```
if (al.stream().anyMatch(stringBuffer -> stringBuffer.toString().equals(str.toString()))) {
```

Comment: Please explain what you are intending to show by this answer. Simply dumping code is not helpful.

Comment: @Bahramdun Adil - Lamba expression was also a new suggestion to me. I tried it, but encoutered the following error. 

Password.java:14: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
                        if (al.stream().anyMatch(stringBuffer -> stringBuffer.toString().equals(str.toString()))) {
                                                                                                ^
1 error

Answer (score 0):

I am here posting the workaround to the problem that I was facing.

The actual problem statement is [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/password-1/).

The following is the code snippet of one of the ways which I implemented to solve the problem statement, using linkedlist:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Password {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        String str;
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            str = sc.next();
            ll.add(str);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            str = (sb.append(ll.get(i))).reverse().toString();
            if (ll.contains(str)) {
                System.out.print(str.length() + " " + str.charAt(str.length()/2)); 
                break;
            }
            sb.setLength(0);
        }
        sc.close(); 
    }
}
```